# No line breaks in syntax highlighted code

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I've installed [Sunburst Code Prettify](http://www.rachelbaker.me/sunburst-code-prettify-wordpress-plugin/) on [my new blog](http://matan.name/wordpress/). The prettifier uses Highlight.js to prettify code. I've placed the following Python code in a post:

```
[prettify class="python"]
>>> s=set(['a','b','c'])
>>> ''.join(s)
'acb'
[/prettify]
```

And got the following highlighting (with some paragraphs for context):

[image]

The line breaks are lost, some `>` were converted to `&#8221`, and there's an annoying gray background behind the rounded black code frame.

I've tried another Highlight.js plugin, [wp-highlight.js](http://www.kalnitsky.org/projects/wp-highlight.js/):

```
[code lang="python"]
>>> s=set(['a','b','c'])
>>> ''.join(s)
'acb'
[/code]
```

And got:

[image]

Same gray background, same loss of line breaks.

I've tried switching themes (currently using Mosaic, switched to the standard Twenty-Ten), with no success.

Any ideas what went wrong?

**Update - what I've tried:**

`<pre>`:

```
<pre>
[prettify class="python"]
>>> s=set(['a','b','c'])
>>> ''.join(s)
'acb'
[/prettify]
</pre>
```

Empty lines:

```
[prettify class="python"]
>>> s=set(['a','b','c'])

>>> ''.join(s)

'acb'
[/prettify]
```

Answer (score 2):

I've found that you have to wrap code formatting shortcodes in pre tags.

Comment: I've entered HTML mode and enclosed the `[prettify]` with `<pre>` and `</pre>`, with no luck: http://matan.name/wordpress/